# Why did Joe give cigars to Team Flash?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

In *The Flash* 4x04 “Elongated Journey Into Night”, there is a scene in the final act when Joe arrives at Star Labs and shows a box of cigars to Team Flash, handing them out to everyone. The scene is silent except for some music, so we can’t hear anybody. However, they seem super excited in a way that I wouldn’t expect for people who don’t appear to be smokers.

Why did Joe give cigars to the team? And why were they so happy about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I recall Joe had just been informed he was to be a father again.

The passing out of cigars to celebrate pregnancy or birth  is a tradition in the US.

See http://www.todays-woman.net/2015/alcohol-and-entertaining/the-cigar-a-timeless-birth-tradition/

Comment: Huh, I live in the US and have never heard of this “timeless” tradition. Maybe it’s a regional or generational thing.